# How to use java update 40 version of Java on NetBeans 8

Tags: java, javafx-8, netbeans-8

I would like to use and test the classes added in Java 8 update 40, but unfortunately the compiler of Netbeans generates an error when i add the following statement:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R>;
```

The following image shows that the JDK installed in my comuter is : java 8 update 40.
[image]

Comment: That is a Java **runtime** (JRE) not a **JDK**

Comment: as far as i know, imports never include the diamond reference. `import javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R>;` should be: `import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;`

Comment: After updating your Java, no need to manually update anything in IDE. You can simply use. Or in worst case, you may restart your Netbeans or system.

Comment: @Vish Unfortunately this is not true. See my answer.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name what does i do? i must reinstall JDK .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in the /etc/netbeans.conf file you configured the correct JDK.

Also as WonderWorld says: Use

```
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
```

instead of

```
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R>;
```

Comment: netbeans.conf file contains the following line:netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

Comment: I have a look at my JDK installation on Windows 7, I see directories like this "jdk1.8.0_<update version>". Can you check if this a link/ shortcut somehow? What is the JDK update version of this installation?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project. Go to properties. Click Build > Compile and change or add jdk_8_u40 platfrom